# Facebook JavaScript SDK: Read App URL

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an app with a secure canvas URL, I'm using the JavaScript SDK.
Let's say this is the url:
https://apps.facebook.com/myappname

I'd like to read in my canvas (inside of an iframe on facebook) the url of the app, so that I can read the request ids passed from notifications.

For example:

https://apps.facebook.com/myappname/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=1590311054517858%2C783489375062266%2C2003963076409280%2C641623095938714%2C610412875770428%2C863733153691513%2C339110779618686%2C417995475034759%2C795906487167590&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_invite

How do I do that?

Comment: That can’t be done, because of the Same Origin Policy. But I would assume that Facebook passes these values on to the app in some way (otherwise having them would make no sense in the first place). If that is done via POST as is done for other app parameters however, you won’t be able to access them via client-side JavaScript, and have to use a server-side technique.

Comment: I recall once seeing a way to do it via the JavaScript SDK, I couldn't find it again.

Comment: I am not aware of any method in the SDK that would allow to do this.

Comment: Nevermind I just noticed it's for the Unity SDK - GetDeepLink.
Could you please elaborate on how to actually do it?

Comment: Go dump the GET and POST parameters your app gets passed when it is called in that way, and see what you get.

Comment: The GET parameters were passed to the iframe's url by facebook, I could access them via plain JS window.location. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The GET parameters were passed to the iframe's url by facebook, I could access them via plain JS window.location.